# Why can't cout a scoped enum class member directly while can for unscoped enum?

Tags: c++

`cout` unscoped enum directly works:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
enum  color { red, green, blue };

int main()
{
    cout << color::green;
    return 0;
}
```

While with socoped enum can't:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
enum class color { red, green, blue };

int main()
{
    cout << color::green;
    return 0;
}
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works because unscoped enums can be implicitly converted to integers, whereas scoped enums can't, and require an explicit conversion:

```
cout << static_cast<int>(color::green);
```

Answer (score 1):

The unscoped enum is automatically converted to some integral type. That's why it will only print out `1`, not `green`.

The scoped enum is not implicitly convertable to an integer and there is not other `operator<<` for `std::cout` so it fails to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe char like optimal attribute help you.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum class Color { red='r', green='g', blue='b' };

int main()
{

    cout << "Print opt attribute: " <<  static_cast<char>(Color::green);
    return 0;
}
```

***Test online :***

https://onlinegdb.com/Syw-qgg97